# React Native (Class Component) Re-render parent component when props of child component change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

On Props change of child tried calling this.componentDidMount() of it and also this.setState({}) with no params.
The parent screen won't rerender.

Comment: can you give some code plz?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe your code's current behavior and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You don't need to manually call the lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`

Comment: the props of  your child component will only change when the state of your parent components changes. Ideally we use callback function(where in we use  this.setState({}) to update the state of the parent) which we pass from parent to child and whenever we want our parent component to re render, we need to invoke that callback function in child. does this answer your query?